# Rails: One-to-many association fails due to foreign key validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, associations, one-to-many

I have set up a one-to-many association in rails, but my test keeps on failing due to a foreign-key not set up properly. I was wondering if anyone had any advice.

I have two models - rota and user. I want a rota to be "created" by a user. A user can create more than one rota.

**Test failing**

*In rota_spec:*

```
it {should belong_to :creator}
Expected Rota to have a belongs_to association called creator (Rota does not have a creator_id foreign key.)
```

*In user_spec:*

```
it {should have_many :created_rotas}
Expected User to have a has_many association called created_rotas (Rota does not have a creator_id foreign key.)
```

---

**Rota.rb**

```
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
```

**User.rb**

```
  has_many :created_rotas, :class_name => "Rota", :foreign_key => "creator_id"
```

**Migration**

```
class AddCreatorToRotas < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :rotas, :creator_id, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you have migrate the database in test?

Comment: ah - no! damn! that probably is it!

Comment: I only migrated the main database - rake db:migrate. If you post it as an answer, I will mark as accepted :)

Comment: shouldn't the creator_id be a integer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must to run

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: Thanks ! It work but why ?
Could anyone explane this ?
I try for amost two hours to fix this

Comment: It loads code in `db/schema.rb`. You can see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/testing.html